# Cancelling a PendingIntent with unique requestCode

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I'm having trouble with cancelling my pendingintent. Right now I create my pending intent like so:

`Intent intent = new Intent(_self, NotificationService.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, task.getID, intent, 0);`

task.getID is a unique int here. Later on in my app a user can edit a "task" and can decide to cancel the notifications (pendingintent). I try to cancel the pendingintent like so:

`Intent intent = new Intent(_self, NotificationService.class);                 PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(_self, task.getID, intent , PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

                        pIntent.cancel();`

But it doens't work! The notifications still shows up. In this case, task.getID refers to the unique id that was created before.

I've tried several different parameters, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE returns null, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT doens't work and FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT neither. Can somebody please help me with this and see what it is I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a service with your PendingIntent and are trying to cancel a Broadcast. It will never work.

You need to getService with the PendingIntent you are trying to cancel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate your pending intent THE EXACT SAME WAY you created the first one when you want to cancel it.

take a look : [Cancelling a PendingIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823408/cancelling-a-pendingintent)

Comment: I do recreate it the exact same way. It doesn't matter if I add the extra's or not, it still doesnt' work :(