# issue while canceling the notification via alarmManger

Tags: java, android

I have a `Notification` that is triggered by an `AlarmManager`. This is my code:

```
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity());

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");

    notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

    PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 5000, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 10000, broadcast);

    alarmManager.cancel(broadcast);
    // here am trying to cancel the notification with PendingIntent but its not working
```

EDIT:

by working i meant its not canceling the notification at is supposed to

Comment: What does 'working' look like? Please refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 5000, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel();
```

instead of `alarmManager.cancel(broadcast)`

thanks to these post [Cancelling a PendingIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823408/cancelling-a-pendingintent)