# Pending Intent in Notification not getting cleared

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

Please have a look at my Pending Intent code.

```
        notificationIntent.putExtra("is_from_notification", true);            
        notificationIntent.putExtra("push_message_id", push_message_id);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("open_target", open_target);
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,notifyID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(icon_small)
                .setTicker(message)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true).build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       notificationManager.notify(notifyID, noti);
```

My Problem is that, where and how should I clear this pending intent. It stays as far as app is in recent tasks.

Comment: didnt get your question...your notification is not getting cleared or you want to cancel this pending intent..???

Comment: do u get notification using above code?

Comment: Yes receiving notification but can not cancel pending intent.

Comment: hi  when you get error message  like " app is in recent tasks."
?

Comment: @Hemant I've editted my answer, to cancel your `pendingIntent` use that one line of code, where ever u want to cancel your `pendingIntent`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823408/cancelling-a-pendingintent

Answer (score 0):

Just call notificationManager.cancel(notifyId);

Or

call notificationManager.cancelAll();

Hope , it helps.

Comment: But your code for cancel notification from status bar. Are you sure it clear pending intent also?

Answer (score -1):

To clear a [pendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) use:

**Edit:**

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context,notifyID, contentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel();
```

Place this line somewhere in your code, where u want to cancel the pendingintent.

**Note:** The intent **must** have the same name and ID as your pendingIntent, in your case: `notifyID` and `contentIntent`

> **Note:** A PendingIntent itself is simply a reference to a token maintained by the system describing the original data used to retrieve it. This means that, even if its owning application's process is killed, the PendingIntent itself will remain usable from other processes that have been given it. If the creating application later re-retrieves the same kind of PendingIntent (same operation, same Intent action, data, categories, and components, and same flags), it will receive a PendingIntent representing the same token if that is still valid, and can thus call **cancel()** to remove it.
>
> [cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#cancel%28%29) - Cancel a currently active PendingIntent. Only the original application owning a PendingIntent can cancel it.

Should help u out

Comment: No. it did not help.

Comment: @Hemant This is only to push u in the right direction. But I've **editted** my answer for your use. It **should work** now!

Comment: it's not working, I put PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), notifyID, getIntent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel(); in current activity. current activity is called from pending intent.

Comment: That's wrong, **getIntent()** must be **contentIntent** this is very **important**, because this indicates that the `pendingIntent` named `contentIntent` should be canceled! just copy my line to your code.

Comment: **contentintent** is in GCMBaseIntentService, and i want to cancel  pending intent from activity which is started by pending intent.

Comment: Well I guess u have to change the context. But this line should cancel your pendingIntent